# JSF printer friendly version of data table

Tags: jsf, printing, datatable

I have a data table whose column can increase dynamically... it can increase up to 20 columns. What is the best way to show the printer friendly version of the table. Should I use Jasper reports. If yes, Jasper reports expects a xml file as source, so how to generate the XML file from the JSP page.

Answer (score 2):

Just supply a CSS file which is read by printers only by specifying `media="print"`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Therein you can just use CSS to set the page orientation (landscape), decrease the font size, decrease margin/padding, hide/show specific columns/cells, or even hide the entire table and show another one.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Your solution will work if the number of columns is less, in this case the column can go upto 50. So, just wondering what is the best possible way.

Comment: How exactly would you like to represent it on the printed page? You would just need to style/code the way so that it look exactly like that.